# I want to make border around three sides of AnchorPane, not four

Tags: css, javafx, border

Make a border around the AnchorPane, but she's four sides appears, of course, and want only on three sides. How to do this?

```
    AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
    pane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: green;");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
 pane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: green; -fx-border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0px");
```

Comment: pane.setStyle("-fx-border: 1px solid green;");

error:
WARNING: CSS Error parsing '*{-fx-border: 1px solid green;}: expected series of <size> while parsing '-fx-border' at [1,14]

Comment: Wrong syntax, I think

Comment: I tried so:
"-fx-border-width: 3,3,0,3;"
it does not work too. Border is on 4 sides

Comment: Updated my answer. Can you try that?

Comment: Oh! It works. And earned my version too:
"-fx-border-width: 3,3,0,3;"

Thank you.

Comment: Can you help me?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822595/to-create-a-partial-border-with-a-hole