# How to create a partial border(with a hole)?

Tags: css, javafx, border

I wrote code in JavaFX and used CSS for setting styles for the above issue. The following code made borders for an AnchorPane that are 2 pixels wide:

```
    AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
    pane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: blue; -fx-border-width: 2");
```

The above code made borders around three sides:

```
    pane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: blue; -fx-border-width: 2 2 0 2;");
```

I want to make borders around all 4 sides, but the top border must have a hole as indicated in the picture below:

[image]

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "nested backgrounds" to generate borders like this:

```
    pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue, -fx-background, -fx-background;"
            + "-fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0 50 2 100, 2 2 2 2;");
```

The [JavaFX CSS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) has all the details, but basically the way this works is that it creates three backgrounds, which are laid one over the other. The first is blue, with insets of 0 on every side. I.e.:

```
pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue; -fx-background-insets 0 0 0 0;");
```

This creates a blue rectangle which fills the entire pane:

[image]

The second background has the default root background from modena (`-fx-background`). It has insets of `0` at the top, `50` to the left, `2` at the bottom, and `100` at the right. So the first two nested backgrounds:

```
pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue, -fx-background;"
        + "-fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0 50 2 100;");
```

produce this:

[image]

Note the 2-pixel wide blue line at the bottom.

Finally, the third background also has the default background color (`-fx-background`), and insets of two pixels on each side. So when this is laid over the previous two backgrounds, the desired effect is seen:

[image]

When the values for all four sides are the same, you can replace the four values with a single value. So the CSS can be abbreviated

```
    pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue, -fx-background, -fx-background;"
            + "-fx-background-insets: 0 , 0 50 2 100, 2;");
```

Just a technical note: the default style sheet is not loaded unless at least one control is created, which is why I add a `Label` in the complete example below.

Here is an SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BorderWithGap extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();

        Label label = new Label("Border with gap");
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(label, 50.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(label, 50.0);
        pane.getChildren().add(label);

        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue, -fx-background, -fx-background;"
                + "-fx-background-insets: 0, 0 50 2 100, 2;");


        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sir, Do you strictly require `CSS` for this? `java` can do it, using `Shape` and `Border`s

[image]

`Nikitoslav.java`

```
public class Nikitoslav extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Pane g = new Pane();        
    g.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.YELLOW,
            null, null)));
    g.relocate(20, 20);
    BorderStroke bs = new BorderStroke(Color.RED, Color.RED, Color.RED, Color.RED,//the paint around th four corners
            BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID,
            null, BorderStroke.THIN, null);
    g.setBorder(new Border(bs));
    Path p = new  Path();
    p.getElements().addAll(new MoveTo(1, 0),new HLineTo(0),new VLineTo(4), new HLineTo(4), new VLineTo(0),
            //creating a rectangle
            new HLineTo(3)
    );
    g.setShape(p);
    g.setPrefSize(300, 300);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(g),500,500));
    primaryStage.show();
    g.setPrefSize(400, 400);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.init();
}

@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.stop();
 }

}
```

With this you don't need nested `Background`s or an array of `Background`s-(*guess that will improve performance*)

To explain my code, well, i created my `Border`s using the `BorderStroke` which `Paint` fills for top-right-bottom-left respectively, specified the type of Color and style, after i created an open rectangle with the `PathElements`. From the x axis i started from **1** then to **0** the drew a vertical line to **4**, the length of the rectangle and drew the bottom width also **4**and drew from a vertical line from length **4** to **0** then drew from width **4** to **3** and left points **2** being the hole

Hope it helps

Comment: That's kind of nice: I haven't investigated the actual `Border` API. On performance, though, assuming your application is already parsing CSS, the JavaFX team always says that the nested background approach performs better than using CSS borders, and I suspect once CSS borders are parsed they're basically converted to something similar to the code in this answer (though I don't know that). Nested backgrounds are basically the approach used for all the JavaFX controls specifically for performance reasons. Caveat: I haven't tested this, just going on what Oracle say.

Answer (score -2):

how about use `:before` ?

`.testbox` is a block element that you want to add the border.

```
.testbox{
    margin:10px;
    border:#000 solid 2px;
}

.testbox:before {
    background: #fff;
    width:300px;
    height: 2px;
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 300px;
    margin: -2px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not valid CSS for a JavaFX application.