# TableView, content of selected rows moves to left side

Tags: javafx, tableview, row

I have created a tableview with css but when I select the row it moves to the left side. What am I missing? p.s. sorry for my English.

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynCgR.png)

my css for tableview:

```
.table-view {
    -fx-base: rgb(250, 95, 9);
    -fx-control-inner-background: transparent;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: rgba(250,95,9,0.88);
    -fx-border-radius: 10px;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-table-header-border-color: rgba(250, 95, 9, 0.88);
    -fx-padding: 5;
    -fx-text-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.table-view .column-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.table-view .column-header, .table-view .filler {
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color:
            transparent
            transparent
            derive(-fx-base, 80%)
            transparent;
    -fx-border-insets: 0 10 1 0;
    -fx-text-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.table-view .column-header .label {
    -fx-font-size: 9pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
    -fx-text-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}
.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:filled:focused:selected {
    -fx-border-color: rgba(250, 95, 9, 0.8);
    -fx-border-radius: 5px;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer added css code

Comment: The default CSS file ([modena](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css)) doesn't use borders on table cells, and the layout doesn't account for borders being present. I guess having different borders for a selected table row versus an unselected row is disrupting the layout of the row. Try to refactor your borders as "nested backgrounds". See, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822595/how-to-create-a-partial-borderwith-a-hole for the general concept of nested backgrounds.